# Writing a different csv file in R using If Else Statement

Tags: r

I am having trouble writing a different csv file in R based on the actual day of the week. If today is Saturday, I want to write `df1`, otherwise I want to write `df2`.

I have my data like so:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Fruit = c("Apples", "Apples", "Apples", "Oranges", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Bananas"),
                  No. = c(2,8,7,1,4,9,6))

df2 <- data.frame(Fruit = c("Apples", "Apples", "Apples", "Oranges", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Bananas"),
                  No. = c(4,16,21,46,6,18,9))
```

I have tried using if else like so:

```
ifelse(format(Sys.time(), "%a") == "Sat", write.csv(df1, "data-today.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE), 
       write.csv(df2, "data-today.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE))
```

But it returns this error:

```
Error in ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos] :  
  replacement has length zero
In addition: warning message:
In rep(no, length.out=len) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: This is a case where you should not use `ifelse`, you should instead is an `if() {} else {}` statement. `ifelse()` is a vectorized function that returns a value. Here you just need to run the test and write a file. Plus in your current code you seem to have mismatched quotes so I'm not sure if that's the case in your real code or not. But make sure you have matched quotes around your file names.

Comment: thank you, I just saw the error with the mismatched quotes and have amended. Is there an example of `if() {} else {}` statement? I have not seen or used these before.

Comment: It would just be `if (format(Sys.time(), "%a") == "Sat") { write.csv(df1, "data-today.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE) } else { write.csv(df2, "data-today.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)) }`. There seems to be a decent description here: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/if-else-statement/

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you so much! I also appreciate the description so I can read up on it and learn further.